# Sum $\leq$ integral

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, summation

Can someone explain me, why:

$$\forall f(x)\nearrow[a...b+1]\Rightarrow \sum^b_{i=a} f(i) \leq \int\limits_a^{b+1} f(x)dx$$

using the fact that $f(a) \leq \int\limits^{a+1}_af(x)dx\leq f(a + 1)$.

And what is the graphic representation of it?

Upd: and why $$\int\limits_a^{b} f(x)dx \leq \sum^b_{i=a} f(i)$$

Comment: See the [left Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Left_Riemann_Sum).

Comment: Other than the request for a picture, why is the one word answer "concavity" insufficient?

Comment: $\sum_{n=a}^b f(n)=\int_a^{b+1} f(\lfloor x\rfloor)dx$

Comment: @EricTowers: Concavity is irrelevant here. It's easy to see that for increasing functions, the statement is true regardless of the concavity of the function, and that there are functions (necessarily non-increasing) of every concavity type for which the statement is false.

Comment: @GregMartin : What is the concavity of that integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just using the inequalities
$f(a) 
\leq \int\limits^{a+1}_af(x)dx
\leq f(a + 1)
$
that you were given
(and should understand
why they are true
since $f$ is nondecreasing).

For the first one

$\begin{array}\\
\sum^b_{i=a} f(i)
& \le \sum^b_{i=a} \int\limits^{i+1}_if(x)dx\\
& =  \int\limits^{b+1}_af(x)dx\\
\end{array}
$

since the first integral
in the sum goes from
$a$ to $a+1$,
the second from
$a+1$ to $a+2$,
and so on,
with the last integral from
$b$ to $b+1$.
These all fit together exactly,
with the resulting integral being
from $a$ to $b+1$.

Note:
The basic integral equality is,
if $a \le b \le c$,
then
$\int_a^b f(x) dx + \int_b^c f(x) dx
= \int_a^c f(x) dx
$.

In the other direction,
to show that
$\int\limits_a^{b} f(x)dx \leq \sum^b_{i=a} f(i)
$,
this can be false.
Suppose that
$f(x) = -1$.
Then the left side is
$-(b-a) = a-b$
and the right side is
$-(b-a+1) = a-b-1 < a-b$.

What is true is
$\sum^b_{i=a} f(i)
\ge \int\limits_{a-1}^{b} f(x)dx
$.

To show this,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum^b_{i=a} f(i)
& \ge \sum^b_{i=a} \int\limits^{i}_{i-1}f(x)dx
\qquad\text{since }  f(i) \ge \int\limits^{i}_{i-1}f(x)dx
\\
& =  \int\limits^{b}_{a-1}f(x)dx\\
\end{array}
$

Also note that
the inequalities are reversed
if $f$ is nonincreasing.

A general form of the inequality
that is true for
all continuous $f$ is
$\min(f, a, b)
\le \frac1{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx
\le \max(f, a, b)
$.
This just says that
the average value of a function
over an interval
is at least its minimum
and at most its maximum.